# Service has a mocked service dependency which returns promise, struggling with testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I have three services. **RequestAuthorizationService** calls the **OAuthAuthorizationDataService** to get the credentials for token based authorization and the credentials will be stored in session storage by **sessionStorageManagerService**, so they are passed through.

The test subject is the call when sessionStorageManagerService.set() method gets the data. I want to be sure whether it is called.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong when I check whether the method called in the then block. The test is always saying that the method has not been called.
I went through a lot of articles here but I could not figure out what to do.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Here are the code:

**requestAuthorizationService**

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var serviceId = 'requestAuthorizationService';

    angular
        .module('dilib')
        .service(serviceId, requestAuthorizationService);

    requestAuthorizationService.$inject = ['$q', 'Restangular', 'cryptoService', 'OAuthAuthenticationDataService', 'sessionStorageManagerService'];

    function requestAuthorizationService($q, Restangular, cryptoService, OAuthAuthenticationDataService, sessionStorageManagerService) {

        //API
        var service = {

            requestAuthorization: requestAuthorization,
        }

        return service;

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function requestAuthorization(user) {

            var defer = $q.defer();

            var userLocal = undefined;

            if (typeof user === "undefined") {

                userLocal = {
                    username: 'visitor',
                    password: cryptoService.getMD5('qwe123')
                };
            } else {

                userLocal = user;

            }

            OAuthAuthenticationDataService.authenticate(userLocal).then(function (result) {

                //To be tested
                sessionStorageManagerService.set('authorizationData',
                {
                    token: result.access_token,
                    username: user.username
                });

                defer.resolve(userdata.username);

            }, function (msg) {

                defer.reject(msg);

            });

            return defer.promise;
        }

    }
})();
```

**OAuthAuthenticationDataService**

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var serviceId = 'OAuthAuthenticationDataService';

    angular
        .module('dilib')
        .service(serviceId, OAuthAuthenticationDataService);

    OAuthAuthenticationDataService.$inject = ['Restangular'];

    function OAuthAuthenticationDataService(Restangular) {

        var OAuthHttpHeader = {
            "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        };

        var oAuthEndpointResource = Restangular.all('/token');

        var service = {

            authenticate : authenticate

        }

        return service;


        function authenticate(user) {

            return oAuthEndpointResource.post('grant_type=password&username=' + user.username + '&password=' + user.password, {}, OAuthHttpHeader);

        }
    }
})();
```

**sessionStorageManagerService**

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var serviceId = 'sessionStorageManagerService';

    angular
        .module('dilib')
        .service(serviceId, sessionStorageManagerService);

    sessionStorageManagerService.$inject = ['localStorageService'];

    function sessionStorageManagerService(localStorageService) {

        var service = {

            get: get,
            set: set

        };

        return service;

        function set(key, val) {

            localStorageService.set(key, val);

        }

        function get(key) {

            return localStorageService.get(key);

        }

    }
})();
```

**Test**

```js
describe('requestAuthorizationService', function () {

    var RestangularProvider,
        localStorageServiceProvider,
        cryptoServiceMockSvc,
        OAuthAuthenticationDataServiceMockSvc,
        sessionStorageManagerServiceMockSvc,
        requestAuthorizationService,
        $q,
        $rootScope;

    beforeEach(function () {

        angular.module('ngAnimate', []);
        angular.module('ngRoute', []);
        angular.module('dilib.layout', []);
        //angular.module('LocalStorageModule', []);
        angular.module('http-auth-interceptor', []);
        //angular.module('restangular', []);

    });

    beforeEach(function () {

        module('dilib', function (_RestangularProvider_, _localStorageServiceProvider_) {

            RestangularProvider = _RestangularProvider_;
            localStorageServiceProvider = _localStorageServiceProvider_;

        });

    });

    //beforeEach(inject());

    beforeEach(function () {

        module(function ($provide) {

            $provide.service('cryptoService', function () {
                this.getMD5 = jasmine.createSpy('getMD5').and.callFake(function (param) {

                    var returnVal;

                    if (param == 'qwe123') {

                        returnVal = '200820e3227815ed1756a6b531e7e0d2';
                    }

                    if (param == 'qwe321') {

                        returnVal = 'blabla';
                    }

                    return returnVal;
                });
            });

            $provide.service('OAuthAuthenticationDataService', function () {
                this.authenticate = jasmine.createSpy('authenticate').and.callFake(function (userObject) {

                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    defer.resolve({ access_token: '1234' });
                    return defer.promise;

                });
            });

            $provide.service('sessionStorageManagerService', function () {

                this.get = jasmine.createSpy('get').and.callFake(function(param) {
                    return param;
                });
                this.set = jasmine.createSpy('set').and.callFake(function(param) {
                    return param;
                });

            });

        });

    });

    beforeEach(inject(function (cryptoService,
                                OAuthAuthenticationDataService,
                                sessionStorageManagerService,
                                _requestAuthorizationService_,
                                _$q_,
                                _$rootScope_) {

        cryptoServiceMockSvc = cryptoService;
        OAuthAuthenticationDataServiceMockSvc = OAuthAuthenticationDataService;
        sessionStorageManagerServiceMockSvc = sessionStorageManagerService;
        requestAuthorizationService = _requestAuthorizationService_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

    }));

    describe('requestAuthorization method', function () {

        describe('OAuth authentication result will be passed through sessionStorageManager', function () {

            it('default value result will be passed through', function () {

                //try 1
                // OAuthAuthenticationDataServiceMockSvc.authenticate().then(function(result) {

                    // console.log('result', result);

                    // expect(sessionStorageManagerServiceMockSvc.set).toHaveBeenCalled();

                // });

                // $rootScope.$digest();

                //try 2
                // OAuthAuthenticationDataServiceMockSvc.authenticate();

                // expect(sessionStorageManagerServiceMockSvc.set).toHaveBeenCalled();

                // $rootScope.$digest();

            });

        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate has fake implementation, which does not call sessionStorageManagerService.

I do not see any sessionStorageManagerService.set call in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help

```
var $scope;
var $q;
var deferred;
var sessionStorageManagerService;
var requestAuthorizationService;
var OAuthAuthenticationDataService;

/* Mock another required modules */

beforeEach(function() {
    angular.mock.module(function($provide) {
        sessionStorageManagerService = jasmine.createSpyObj('sessionStorageManagerService', ['set', 'get']);

        $provide.value('sessionStorageManagerService', sessionStorageManagerService);
    });
});

beforeEach(function() {
    angular.mock.module(function($provide) {
        OAuthAuthenticationDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj('OAuthAuthenticationDataService', ['authenticate']);

        $provide.value('OAuthAuthenticationDataService', OAuthAuthenticationDataService);
    });
});

beforeEach(function() {
    angular.mock.module(function($provide) {
        requestAuthorizationService = jasmine.createSpyObj('requestAuthorizationService', ['requestAuthorization']);

        $provide.value('requestAuthorizationService', requestAuthorizationService);
    });
});

beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$q_, _sessionStorageManagerService_, _requestAuthorizationService_, _OAuthAuthenticationDataService_) {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $q = _$q_;
    sessionStorageManagerService = _sessionStorageManagerService_;
    requestAuthorizationService = _requestAuthorizationService_;
    OAuthAuthenticationDataService = _OAuthAuthenticationDataService_;
    deferred = $q.defer();

requestAuthorization.requestAuthorization.and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
OAuthAuthenticationDataService.authenticate.and,returnValue(deferred.promise);

    $scope.$digest();
}));

it('', function() {
    var user = {};

    requestAuthorizationService.requestAuthorization(user);
    deferred.resolve({});
    $scope.$digest();

    expect(OAuthAuthenticationDataService.authenticate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
    expect(sessionStorageManagerService.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
});

it('', function() {
    var user = {};

    requestAuthorizationService.requestAuthorization(user);
    deferred.reject({});
    $scope.$digest();

    expect(...);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I understand correctly that, the example above you inject the original services and you put spyObjects on the particular methods?

Comment: Yes. I created all services as jasmine spy objects. And functions that return promises must return deferred.promise. For testing success or error result of function use deferred resolve/reject and $scope.$digest or $scope.$apply to resolve all promises.